# reading large JSON file in Python (raw_decode)

Tags: python, json

I am trying to read in large JSON file (data.json) in Python. Because the JSON file has multiple JSON objects, and multiple dictionaries will be created in Python(the number of dictionaries are unknown), I used decoder.raw_decode() and generator. 
The following is the code:

```
import json
import pprint
import io
import pprint

def parse():

    with open('data.json',encoding='utf-8') as jfile:
        try:
            while True:
                decoder = json.JSONDecoder()
                obj, idx = decoder.raw_decode(jfile)
                yield obj
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)
            pass
        else:
            print("aha")


def main():
    imputd=parse()
    if imputd: 
        while True:
            try:
                print(str(next(imputd)).readlines())
            except StopIteration as e:
                print(e)
                break

main()
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\Document\Python\j10.py", line 57, in <module>
    main()
  File "H:\Document\Python\j10.py", line 36, in main
    print(str(next(imputd)).readlines())
  File "H:\Document\Python\j10.py", line 21, in parse
    obj, idx = decoder.raw_decode(jfile)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\json\decoder.py", line 360, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
TypeError: first argument must be a string, not _io.TextIOWrapper
```

I edited code based on Martijn's answer:

```
import json
import io



file=open('data.json.txt')
def readin():
    return file.read(2000)


def parse():
    decoder = json.JSONDecoder()
    buffer = ''    
    for chunk in iter(readin, ''):
        buffer += chunk
        while buffer:
            try:
                result, index = decoder.raw_decode(buffer)
                yield result
                buffer = buffer[index:]
            except ValueError:
                 # Not enough data to decode, read more
                break

def main():
    imputd=parse()
    if imputd: 
        while True:
            try:
                print(str(next(imputd)).readlines())
            except StopIteration as e:
                print(e)
                break

main()
```

and I get an UnicodeError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\Document\Python\j11.py", line 35, in <module>
    main()
  File "H:\Document\Python\j11.py", line 30, in main
    print(str(next(imputd)).readlines())
  File "H:\Document\Python\j11.py", line 14, in parse
    for chunk in iter(readin, ''):
  File "H:\Document\Python\j11.py", line 8, in readin
    return file.read(2000)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 4217: character maps to <undefined>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing in the file object, but `decoder.raw_decode()` only takes *text data*. You need to do the reading yourself:

```
obj, idx = decoder.raw_decode(jfile.read())
```

You are then yielding *Python objects created from the JSON data*, so your `.readlines()` call in your `main()` function loop will also fail.

You are not using `raw_decode()` correctly, however. You are yourself responsible for feeding it chunks of text, it'll not read that text from the file for you. If you wanted to handle the file in chunks, and there are no clear delimiters between the JSON entries, you'll be forced to read the file in blocks:

```
decoder = json.JSONDecoder()
buffer = ''
for chunk in iter(partial(jfile.read, buffersize), ''):
     buffer += chunk
     while buffer:
         try:
             result, index = decoder.raw_decode(buffer)
             yield result
             buffer = buffer[index:]
         except ValueError:
             # Not enough data to decode, read more
             break
```

This will still yield completely decoded objects; if your file is *one long JSON object* (like one top-level list or dictionary) then this'll not yield the contents of that object one by one; it'll still read the whole object before yielding.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply!!I really appreciated it. I think it definitely works! It's just my Json data may contain some data error//so now I am trying to figure out how to deal with the UnicodeError.

Comment: @xccccx: you should really make that a separate question; your initial issue was resolved. You opened the file without specifying an encoding, so the default codec is used and that is the wrong codec for that file. For JSON data I'd expect it to use UTF-8 instead, so use `open('data.json.text', encoding='utf8')` instead. If that doesn't work you'll have to figure out what the encoding was instead, but I don't have the context to help with that.

Comment: This only works if there isn't a line break between json objects.  if it looks like }\n{, the add while buffer[0] == '\n':
                    buffer = buffer[1:] after buffer = buffer[index:].  naturally a real programmer will have a better suggestion, but this hack worked for me.

Comment: @HenriettaMartingale: see [How do I use the 'json' module to read in one JSON object at a time?](//stackoverflow.com/a/21709058) as well; there I added a `.lstrip()` to clear out intermediate whitespace.

Comment: @HenriettaMartingale: but if your JSON objects are always separated by newlines, the use `for chunk in jfile:` (and optionally replace all uses of the name `chunk` with `line`) to just read the file a line at a time.