# PySpark reading JSON without line breaks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using pyspark to read in JSON from s3 using:

`>>>spark.read.json('s3a://somejsonfile).show(100)`

The issue is the JSON is not separated by `\n`

I tried using reading in the file first then using split on `'}{'`, then feeding it back in but not sure how to do it properly. There has to be a way to do this with spark right?

edit: there are multiple JSON objects in the file so the multiline option doesn't work

Comment: What are the JSON object separated by in the file?

Comment: No separation, just back to back so '}{'

Answer (score 0):

If the json is not separated by line breaks and it appears in a sequence like }{, read the entire file as text, Use regex to identify and separate individual JSON objects, and then read them as individual records. Something like this:

```
import re

rdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile('s3a://somejsonfile')
content = rdd.collect()[0]

Use regex to split the JSON objects
pattern = r'\}(?=\{)'
jsons = [json_ + '}' for json_ in re.split(pattern, content)]

# Convert the list back to an RDD
json_rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(jsons)

Convert each JSON string to a DataFrame record
df = spark.read.json(json_rdd)

df.show(100)
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample json content like what was described in the question:

```
{"a":1, "b":2}{"a":3,"b":4}
```

I read the content of the file as text, replaced the `}{` pattern with `}|{`, then split the string by `|`, defined a schema that's applicable to json content, and finally applied the schema to the elements of the split string:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Create a SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

initial_df = (
    spark.read.text('./test_json.json', wholetext = True)
    .select(f.split(f.regexp_replace(f.col('value'), '\}\{', '\}\|\{'), '\|').alias('value'))
)
initial_df.show(truncate = False)

schema = 'a int, b int'
json_df = (
    initial_df
    .withColumn('json_content', f.explode(f.expr(f'transform(value, x -> from_json(x, "{schema}"))')))
    .select(f.col('json_content.*'))
)
json_df.show(truncate = False)
```

And the output looks like this:

```
initial_df:
+-------------------------------+
|value                          |
+-------------------------------+
|[{"a":1, "b":2}, {"a":3,"b":4}]|
+-------------------------------+

json_df:
+---+---+
|a  |b  |
+---+---+
|1  |2  |
|3  |4  |
+---+---+
```